# Running a program using shell_exec in PHP, how to know if process is done?

Tags: php, shell-exec

Hi I am running a python script inside PHP using the shell_exec command,
However how would I know if the execution of the python has been completed already?

Here is portion of my code

```
$py_path = 'app/public/engines/validation/delta';        
chdir($py_path);                    
$py_var = 'python scraped_data.py';                   
$exec = shell_exec($py_var);
```

How would I know if the python is finished its processing?
I wanted to know because I have a series of processes to run but it needs the first process to be completed first.

Thank You,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) description of shell_exec() is:

> shell_exec — Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string

So you can edit your python script to output true or 1 once script is finished.

then you can simply code something like this:

```
$py_path = 'app/public/engines/validation/delta';        
chdir($py_path);                    
$py_var = 'python scraped_data.py';                   
$exec = shell_exec($py_var);
If($exec){
//Execute another script or do what you wish
}
```

Comment: Can you help me on why my shell_exec does not work for my python command,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65612905/php-shell-exec-not-responding-on-python-command
Thank You