# PHP shell_exec is not responding on python command line

Tags: php, shell-exec

Hi I am running `shell_exec` on my PHP Application,
Here is the code,

```
$path = "C:/scripts/";
chdir($path);
$py_commonscript = 'python Common_Script.py';
$exec = shell_exec($py_commonscript);

echo "<pre>$exec</pre>";
```

This code doesn't give any result and does not generate a file.
When I tried running manually on the command line it is working and was able to generate a file.

I tried to execute this one below and it was able to display some result.

```
$sample = shell_exec('ls -lart');
echo "<pre>$sample </pre>";
```

I am wondering why the command for `$exec` is not being triggered or run.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is that your PHP code isn't inheriting a %PATH containing python.exe. Try `print getenv('PATH');` or just use the full path to python.exe in your command line.